# React: Why is my variable only defined on the first render but undefined on subsequent renders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, use-effect

React noob here.

I am having a hard time understanding how the useEffect and useState hooks work.

My App fetches data which upon retrieval needs to be rendered.

I am using the then() function to ensure that the variables are defined in the correct order. I have also tried using multiple useEffect() functions to guarantee the proper chronology. However, for whatever reason, my `current` variable is undefined. It is only defined on the first render.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Answers() {

  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([])
  const [current, setCurrent] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/questions')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setQuestions(data))
      .then(setCurrent(questions[0]))
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {console.log(current['answers'])}
        {current['answers'].map(item => <li>{item}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Here is the data being fetched:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "to work",
      "answers": ["yapmak", "gitmek", "çalışmak", "gelmek"],
      "correct": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "to know",
      "answers": ["gitmek", "bilmek", "çalışmak", "gelmek"],
      "correct": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "to want",
      "answers": ["istemek", "gitmek", "çalışmak", "konuşmak"],
      "correct": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can assign an Initial value so It's available for the first render.
`const [questions, setQuestions] = useState([
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "to work",
      "answers": ["yapmak", "gitmek", "çalışmak", "gelmek"],
      "correct": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "question": "to know",
      "answers": ["gitmek", "bilmek", "çalışmak", "gelmek"],
      "correct": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "question": "to want",
      "answers": ["istemek", "gitmek", "çalışmak", "konuşmak"],
      "correct": 1
    }
  ])`

Answer (score 3):

Code inside the `useEffect` hook is not doing what you probably expect.

First of all

```
.then(setCurrent(questions[0]))
```

will immediately call the function. You probably meant to write:

```
.then(() => setCurrent(questions[0]))
```

but that's still not correct because `questions[0]` will be `undefined`.

To understand why it will be `undefined`, you need to know two things about state update in React:

- It is updated asynchronously
- It is constant within a particular render of a component. Component can't see the updated state until it re-renders

In light of the above two points, we cannot use `questions` in the third `then()` method's callback function.

What you need to do is *return* the `data` from the 2nd `then` method's callback function as shown below:

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/questions')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => { 
      setQuestions(data);
      return data; 
   })
   .then(data => setCurrent(data[0]))
```

Returning `data` from the callback of second `then()` method's callback function is needed to pass the `data` from the callback function of second `then()` to the callback function of third `then()` method.

#### Remove unnecessary "then()" method call

You don't really need the last `then()` method to call `setCurrent` - you can call it inside the second `then()` method.

```
fetch('http://localhost:8000/questions')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(data => { 
      setQuestions(data);
      setCurrent(data[0]);
   })
```

#### Using the useEffect hook

Alternative option is to update `current` state inside another `useEffect` hook that executes whenever `questions` state is updated.

*(following `useEffect` hook will execute *after* `questions` state has been updated and the component has re-rendered as a result of that state update)*

```
useEffect(() => {
  setCurrent(questions[0]);
}, [questions]);
```

If you take this approach, then the first `useEffect` could be re-written as:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('http://localhost:8000/questions')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setQuestions(data))
    .catch(error => { /* handle error */ });
}, []);
```

---

**Note:** Not related to your problem but you shouldn't omit the `catch()` method call to catch and handle any errors during the HTTP request.

Comment: What about performance when using another `useEffect` hook? Will the component be rendered twice for each `fetch`?

Comment: @marzelin Asynchronous state updates are not batched (this behavior will [change in React 18](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/21)); so even without the second `useEffect`, there will be two re-renders. Personally, instead of having second state for the current question, I would prefer saving the index of the current question in `React.useRef(...)`

Comment: there's no point to `setCurrent` in another `then`. You should move it to the previous one.

Comment: @marzelin yes ofcourse. Edited to show that approach as well.

Comment: `useEffect` runs after the changes are committed to the DOM. I'd rather use `useLayoutEffect` for calling `setCurrent` to have both changes committed in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the way you set the `current` value, when you're calling `setCurrent`, the `questions` state is not ready yet. Try adding an additional `useEffect` hook that reacts to changes in `questions`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/questions')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setQuestions(data))
  }, []);

useEffect(() => {
    if (questions) {
        setCurrent(questions[0]);
    }
}, [questions]);
```